# Why the example of SHUFFLE of OpenCL is not valid?

Tags: opencl

There is an example of `shuffle` of OpenCL during the [document](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/shuffle.html).

```
//Examples that are not valid are:
uint8 mask;
short16 a;
short8 b;
b = shuffle(a, mask); // invalid
```

But I can not understand why. I test this during Android with AndroidStudio, and the result said:**build program failed:BC-src-code:9:9:{9:9-9:16}: error: no matching builtin function for call to 'shuffle'**. Then, I change the **short** to **int**, like this:

```
uint8 mask;
int16 a;
int8 b;
b = shuffle(a, mask);
```

and it is ok.  I can not find any reason from the document, can anybody help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the critical part of the description in the spec is this:

> The size of each element in the mask must match the size of each element in the result.

I take that to mean that if you want to shuffle a vector of `short`s, your mask must be a vector of `ushort`; a mask of `uint8` would only be valid for shuffling vectors with elements of 4 bytes - in other words, `int`, `uint`, and `float`.

So the following should be valid again:

```
ushort8 mask; // <-- changed
short16 a;
short8 b;
b = shuffle(a, mask); // now valid
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right according to my test. But I cannot understand the benefits of this rule . Also, I found that the *mask* must be **unsigned type**, which not be mentioned during the doc. `ushort8 mask;` is ok, and `short8 mask;` will fail. Maybe, this is related to platform.

Comment: The requirement of the mask being unsigned is indicated by it being [declared as `ugentype`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/shuffle.html). I guess the rule of component types being the same size is perhaps so that the same SIMD register can be used? In any case it shouldn‘t be hard to follow once you know about it.